# How to get 'Hour and day of the week' report using AWQL

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, awql

Using ad scheduling on AdWords in my Search Network only campaign I can see 'Hour and day of the week' report. It shows campaign performance values on a given day and time. I would like to utilize this data in AdWords script. Is it possible to access them through AdWordsApp class or AWQL? If so then how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DayOfWeek` and `HourOfDay` are segments on a `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` so you can certainly get the same thing using AWQL.

For example:

```sql
SELECT CampaignName,CampaignId,Impressions,Clicks,ConvertedClicks,DayOfWeek,HourOfDay
FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
DURING LAST_MONTH
```

Comment: How can i get DIMENSIONS tab data on HourOfDay for an adgroup?